# What can I do? - Beating Wandering In The Dark

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm currently trying to do "Wandering In The Dark" (NG+) on "Death March!" difficulty. I am up to the part where Keira needs to shut the portals, and I have to face Hounds of The Wild Hunt.

I am struggling to even get past the first portal, and the most hounds I have killed at once is one.

I am currently level 37 and equipped with 4 Enhanced Swallow potions, 3 Full moon, 1 Tawny Owl and only got 3 Viziman Champion for food and drink. I also have a few bombs.

I've tried to stay close to Keira as much as possible and parry incoming attacks and use Igni as crowd control. It goes alright for a bit, but once the hounds get so low they start to regenerate health so I try to be a bit more aggressive and finish them off asap. Then after I get the first one, another one comes and by then I have ran out of all my potions and it just kills me.

Is there something else I should try? Is there a way for me to get out of the quest and go do other quests in the mean time, or should I go back to my original playthrough, level up my character a bit more, get better gear and start NG+ again?

Comment: What is the actual recommended level for the quest in your playthrough? Have you used all your ability points to build up your character?

Comment: The recommended level is 39 and I have used up all my ability points.

Comment: Perhaps try getting to level 39 then. The bonuses gained from those two levels may very well tip the balance in your favor.

Comment: Probably a good idea, I've only just realised I am able to leave the quest and go do other ones.

Comment: Your equipment and level is really subpar. Why only enhanced swallow? You can easily get all potions to superior on normal and if I recall correctly potions carry over to NG+. Why only lvl 37? Do you play without the expansions? Because you easily reach lvl 45-50 in B&W on normal game.

Comment: I play without the expansions, I did recently get them but I don't understand exactly how they work.

Comment: I've gone back to my original play-through and am now playing the expansions. Once I have finished both, I'll start NG+ again and I should be in a much better position than before this time around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't parry monsters. *Dodge*.  Parry is great for stopping one handed weapons and, with the right skill, incoming arrows and bolts. But with monsters & two handed weapons you just don't want to be where the blow falls.
2. Given the tight space you've got to work with I make heavy use of Yrden here.
3. Given that this is NG+, surely you have an Ekimmara Decoction available.  This will help keep your health up.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended level is probably a minimum.

A strong Quen shield helps as does using the Ekhidna decoction which regenerates health whenever you cast a sign.

A fully scaled up Aerondight sword from the Blood and Wine DLC makes things a lot simpler as it is always very strong. Don't forget to use the correct blade oil.

Try and find all the formulae for the Superior potions.

Comment: I've found Aerondight to be great for non-combat specs.  On my last playthrough, I used a combat heavy spec and found that scaling up Aerondight became *very* difficult.  Things just died before I could rack up the 10 charges.

Comment: One way to scale Aerondight is to find an area with 10+ drowners or nekkers (east of Reardon Manor for example) - even if you one hit kill them the 10th kill will scale. You do need to focus on scaling up the sword for a while.

Comment: True, but meditating long enough, often enough, to repeatedly farm these locations feels a bit exploity.  In my 1st playthrough with a mostly Alchemy spec, Aerondight just kept itself maxed without any funny business.